# Should Python $PATH be same in .profile, .bash.profile, .profile.pysave?

Tags: python, bash, macos, dependencies

On Mac OS X I had a few versions of Python installed for use with afdk (a font modifying module). I was advised to remove them and start over, which I have done.

Looking at .profile,  .bash.profile,  .profile.pysave files, I see that all previous versions I installed are noted. In order to use to use only the latest Python version, should I hack these .bash files by removing old versions, and only keep the $PATH for the current Python version ?

```
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/adrianshome/bin/FDK/Tools/osx
```

Thanks,
Adrian

So here are the mentioned .bash files below.

.profile:

```
##
# DELUXE-USR-LOCAL-BIN-INSERT
# (do not remove this comment)
##
echo $PATH | grep -q -s "/usr/local/bin"
if [ $? -eq 1 ] ; then
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
    export PATH
fi

# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.5
# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
# Initialization for FDK command line tools.Sun Oct 14 12:28:07 2018
FDK_EXE="/Users/adrianshome/bin/FDK/Tools/osx"
PATH=${PATH}:"/Users/adrianshome/bin/FDK/Tools/osx"
export PATH
export FDK_EXE
```

.profile.pysave:

```
##
# DELUXE-USR-LOCAL-BIN-INSERT
# (do not remove this comment)
##
echo $PATH | grep -q -s "/usr/local/bin"
if [ $? -eq 1 ] ; then
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
    export PATH
fi

# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.5
# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# Initialization for FDK command line tools.Wed May 21 12:21:59 2008
FDK_EXE="/Users/adrianwi/bin/FDK/Tools/osx"
PATH=${PATH}:"/Users/adrianwi/bin/FDK/Tools/osx"
```

.bash.profile:

```
# Initialization for FDK command line tools.Fri Apr 10 14:12:30 2015

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
```

Here is the result of installing Python3 and AFDK modules...

```
Last login: Sun Oct 14 12:50:11 on ttys001
Adrians-iMac-2:~ adrianshome$ pip3 install --user --upgrade afdko;
Collecting afdko
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/d2/0ba8ccfe42b0f88b0cc2819b73d93d4ad6240285a8d9a6a1570f39b1e613/afdko-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (2.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.4MB 543kB/s 
Collecting ufoLib~=2.3.1 (from afdko)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/72/e053c7f9adc52ee7f4ac163cebef4c8d39732a79a02f9abcfdcfbca35785/ufoLib-2.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (109kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 525kB/s 
Collecting ufonormalizer~=0.3.5 (from afdko)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/f3/cdf8d7616cde052b07f3fb83eec34a4a534965df71968cbef9f3895a31c3/ufonormalizer-0.3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting defcon~=0.5.3 (from afdko)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/e5/7491cd6b2f5ec7ef96804f31b8c5fd4d8030d2ff7f331fc2c179ff196bfa/defcon-0.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (212kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 1.6MB/s 
Collecting booleanOperations~=0.8.0 (from afdko)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/98/4c43398f43b023803609ac4ab46b02f10936ba501c8e53e70ee8f21d794d/booleanOperations-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting fontTools~=3.29.1 (from afdko)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/68/a583423ac2ca5dd624ca4914ee97307b4b61a83dda5e0451f0242f628f58/fonttools-3.29.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (612kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 614kB 551kB/s 
Collecting psautohint==1.8.1 (from afdko)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/95/4583fcdb5cca5efe32c46dfa2bab95fcf2a99f43a8fd201971b5978d4705/psautohint-1.8.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (377kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 486kB/s 
Collecting mutatorMath~=2.1.1 (from afdko)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/26/6d1583731da1d236f917b6618ac342ad435eb761750f934f1fc1bfd9ae84/MutatorMath-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting fontMath~=0.4.7 (from afdko)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/b2/6e4d8fd1c0c82f42961dd4e901ecf819e490a64f2abb0a7bdf5082997a4f/fontMath-0.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting fontPens~=0.1.0 (from afdko)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/11/0ad531d40c608eb3b798bb94607b10109b4e145142fe68eda40e92b84daf/fontPens-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyclipper>=1.0.5 (from booleanOperations~=0.8.0->afdko)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/2f/6a75e90bfb924118bd65cc16ccd23df53db697f0df7a4dfa79c6d64913fe/pyclipper-1.1.0.post1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (275kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 510kB/s 
Installing collected packages: fontTools, ufoLib, ufonormalizer, defcon, pyclipper, booleanOperations, psautohint, fontMath, mutatorMath, fontPens, afdko
  The scripts fonttools, pyftinspect, pyftmerge, pyftsubset and ttx are installed in '/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script ufonormalizer is installed in '/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script psautohint is installed in '/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts autohint, buildcff2vf, buildmasterotfs, charplot, checkoutlinesufo, comparefamily, digiplot, fontplot, fontplot2, fontsetplot, hintplot, makeinstancesufo, makeotf, otc2otf, otf2otc, stemhist, ttfcomponentizer, ttxn and waterfallplot are installed in '/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed afdko-2.8.2 booleanOperations-0.8.0 defcon-0.5.3 fontMath-0.4.7 fontPens-0.1.0 fontTools-3.29.1 mutatorMath-2.1.1 psautohint-1.8.1 pyclipper-1.1.0.post1 ufoLib-2.3.2 ufonormalizer-0.3.5
Adrians-iMac-2:~ adrianshome$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/adrianshome/bin/FDK/Tools/osx
Adrians-iMac-2:~ adrianshome$ 
Adrians-iMac-2:~ adrianshome$
```

**UPDATE: 2 NOVEMBER**

Thanks for very good explanation! I reinstalled Python3 and did 'pip3 install --user --upgrade afdko' to get the fonttools modules I need. Created a Virtual Environment. Then ran my code routine again with errors about modules not found in 'site-packages' directory -even though they are there:

Drag ttx to Terminal

Paste code to create 'Dsig fldr' on the Desktop with a dsig.ttx file in it.

Entered '-m '

Drag 'SassoInfProReg.ttf' to Terminal

Drag 'dsig.ttx' to Terminal

RETURN

With this result (apologies for code not all monospaced?)...

```
(env37) Adrians-iMac-2:Dsig fldr adrianshome$ FLDR="${HOME}/Desktop/Dsig fldr"
```

(env37) Adrians-iMac-2:Dsig fldr adrianshome$ mkdir -p "$FLDR"
(env37) Adrians-iMac-2:Dsig fldr adrianshome$ cd "$FLDR"
(env37) Adrians-iMac-2:Dsig fldr adrianshome$ cat > dsig.ttx<

> 00000001 00000000
>   
>   
>   
>   EOF
>   (env37) Adrians-iMac-2:Dsig fldr adrianshome$ open .
>   (env37) Adrians-iMac-2:Dsig fldr adrianshome$ /Library/Python/3.7/bin/ttx -m /Users/adrianshome/Desktop/Dsig\ fldr/SassoInfProReg.ttf /Users/adrianshome/Desktop/Dsig\ fldr/dsig.ttx

Compiling "/Users/adrianshome/Desktop/Dsig fldr/dsig.ttx" to "/Users/adrianshome/Desktop/Dsig fldr/dsig.ttf"...
Parsing 'DSIG' table...
ERROR: Unhandled exception has occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/fontTools/ttx.py", line 398, in main
    process(jobs, options)

File "/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/fontTools/ttx.py", line 372, in process
    action(input, output, options)

File "/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/fontTools/misc/loggingTools.py", line 375, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/fontTools/ttx.py", line 290, in ttCompile
    ttf.save(output)

File "/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/fontTools/ttLib/ttFont.py", line 173, in save
    writer_reordersTables = self._save(tmp)

File "/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/fontTools/ttLib/ttFont.py", line 212, in _save
    self._writeTable(tag, writer, done, tableCache)

File "/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/fontTools/ttLib/ttFont.py", line 633, in _writeTable
    tabledata = self.getTableData(tag)

File "/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/fontTools/ttLib/ttFont.py", line 651, in getTableData
    return self.tables[tag].compile(self)

File "/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/fontTools/ttLib/tables/D_S_I_G_.py", line 60, in compile
    packed = sstruct.pack(DSIG_HeaderFormat, self)

File "/Users/adrianshome/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/fontTools/misc/sstruct.py", line 68, in pack
    value = obj[name]
KeyError: 'ulVersion'
(env37) Adrians-iMac-2:Dsig fldr adrianshome$

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need to do with Python, sometimes your operating system (Linux in most cases) comes with a pre-installed version of Python which is a requirement of a lot of built in functionality. By removing or changing the system wide version you may negatively impact how your system operates. I'm not quite sure if this is the case with OSX as I have limited experience with it.

It's fairly common practise these days for Python applications to install their own local version of python (virtual environment) where they can install their own dependencies and not pollute or negatively impact the system wide version of it.

If you're sure nothing else uses it then it's probably safe to change it but perhaps first rename the directory and see what happens (or breaks) before you go and delete it.

Regarding your relevant profile files:

> .profile.pysave

No need to modify this, it's just a backup that is created when you install python as it modifies your existing .profile but makes a backup in case you wanted to roll back.

In your .profile file you can combine all the paths into a single variable and then export it. For example

```
PATH=${PATH}:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Users/adrianshome/bin/FDK/Tools/osx 
export PATH
```

> .bash.profile

This is a little trickier ... what are you trying to achieve here?

Do you only want to use the latest version of python or are you trying to use all three at once?

I think you may want to just have a single entry with the latest version. Having all three as you do will conflict with each other and will not have the expected behaviour.

The way that PATH works is that it looks for executables in the directories you list in there in the order you specify them. So if you have a path like this

```
PATH=/dir1:/dir2:/dir3
```

And in each of those three directories if you have a file called "python"(assuming its set to executable and you have the appropriate permissions) any time you type "python" in your terminal you will actually be calling /dir1/python as it's the first entry in the PATH.

As you can see that will cause problems if you actually want to use the "python" thats in /dir3.

If you do need to use multiple versions of python I would highly recommend using virtual environments (google virtualenv). These will allow you to have an isolated version of python which you "activate" when needed.

So for example I have two programs, App1 uses python 2.7 and App2 uses python 3.7 and I have two virtual environments. I would activate them like this (note this is an example, exact path will depend where you create it).

```
$ /Users/adrianshome/py2.7/bin/activate
$ App1
```

## Now your python 2.7 is active and is first in the path so when you type python you'll get python 2.7

Similarly you would do the following to run App2

```
$ deactivate (this will undo what you did previously)
$ /Users/adrianshome/py3.7/bin/activate
$ App2
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Do the .bash files (added above) need to be edited in any way? Is there a simple test I can do in Mac OS Terminal command line to check .bash files function correctly?